# Get jasmine configuration during runtime

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

do extend my `jasmine.json` file  with some custom properties such as a server config for the server I want to send my requests to. As I also want to use this config in my tests, I need to read the `jasmine.json` properties during runtime.

Of course I can `require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'jasmine.json'))`. But this soultion would not work when specifying a different location of `jasmine.json` when executing jasmine.

I assume there is at least one way to read the config during runtime, but it is definetly **NOT** `jasmine.config`or `jasmine.getConfig()`.

Any ideas how to retrieve the configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to access jasmine config through it's built-in API.

However there is still an option to achieve this through a workaround, as there are 3 possibilities to find the config:

```
const path = require('path');

const getJasmineConfig = () => {
    // by default jasmine is using below path to find config file
    let configPath = 'spec/support/jasmine.json';

    const configArg = process.argv.find(arg => arg.indexOf('--config') > -1);

    if (configArg) {
        // if config path is specified by --config arg in cli
        configPath = configArg.replace('--config=', '');
    }
    else if (process.env.JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH) {
        // if config path is specified by environment variable
        configPath = process.env.JASMINE_CONFIG_PATH;
    }

    return require(path.resolve(process.cwd(), configPath));
};
```

But yet again - it's not officially supported nor recommended by Jasmine.

Instead of using jasmine.json for this kind of things, you could create your own, project specific config file, i.e. `project.config.js`

and create a service that would serve you the config when needed.